# Socket Io with Android

Tags: android, socket.io

I am using this socket lib for implementation of chat App in Android [socket chat](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client-java).
i am using Emitter for sending messages and Listener for getting response. but i want to edit messages after sent messages to server.Is it possible in socket or not?

Answer (score 0):

No its not possible by using socket.io emitter. Once you emit something and server receives then you cant change the emitted event.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible. Simply edit the object whenever it reaches server. From there u can do whatever you choose with the edited object, most likely that would be send it to its final destination. I assume this means you are using node js so knowledge of js is required. You would edit the js object as seen in the link below.
[Edit Object Item with Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10260731/edit-object-item-with-javascript)